# How to extract two value from json under one condition and randomize it in jmeter?

Tags: groovy, jmeter, performance-testing

Below is the server response in a JSON format which I need to work on, In this JSON some of the objects I need to pass in the next request, which I am successfully able to do for the first occurrence, but the problem is coming on randomization in the below JSON

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "price": 8.95
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                "title": "test_title",
                "price": 12.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Herman Melville",
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
                "price": 8.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
                "title": "India",
                "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
                "price": 22.99
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

if I apply $..book[0][?(@.title == 'Sword of Honour')] condition I am seeing successful output
test_1={"category":"reference","title":"Sword of Honour","author":"Nigel Rees","price":8.95}
test_2={"category":"fiction","title":"Sword of Honour","author":"Herman Melville","price":8.99,"isbn":"0-553-21311-3"}

if I apply $..book[0][?(@.title == 'Sword of Honour')].author condition I am seeing successful output
test_1=Nigel Rees
test_2=Herman Melville

But I want to extract both author's name and price for the book that has the title == 'Sword of Honour'
Actual output = able to retrieve one value with the condition $..book[0][?(@.title == 'Sword of Honour')].author
Expected output = I want to receive two values from the same list randomly. and it should look like this
Iteration 1-
test_1={"author":"Nigel Rees","price":8.95}
Iteration 2-
test_2={"author":"Herman Melville","price":8.99,}
Iteration 3-
test_2={"author":"Herman Melville","price":8.99,}

I had tried with the V function as well but got only one value. (book{__V([?(@.title == 'Sword of Honour')]_${__Random(1,${title_matchNr},)},)})

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def swords = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).store.book.findAll { book -> book.title == 'Sword of Honour' }

   swords.eachWithIndex { def sword, int index ->
       def payload = [:]
       payload.put('author', sword.author)
       payload.put('price', sword.price)
       vars.put('test_' + (index + 1), new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString())
   }
   vars.put('test_matchNr', swords.size() as String)
   ```
3. Now you should be able to refer random author/price pair using [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) and [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) functions combination like: `${__V(test_${__Random(1,${test_matchNr},)},)}`

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)